# Assigning employees marked as inactive to a managers marjed as active

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS empdb;
 
-- create tables
CREATE TABLE emp_status (
   Id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, status VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
 
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    emp_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES emp_status (id)
);


-- insert data for emp_status table
INSERT INTO emp_status(status) VALUES ('active');


-- insert data for employees table
INSERT INTO employees(emp_name,status)      
VALUES('Mary Doe', 'inactive'),
      ('Cindy  'inactive'),
      ('Sue Greenspan',  'inactive');
```

Comment: Please pardon my scattered code.. I want to  be able to assign every employee to a manager. E.g a database with 10 managers i.e 10 rows and each has a column marked as 'active'. I want every new employee to be marked as 'inactive' by default and assigned to each manager sequentially. The employee only becomes marked as active when the manager accredits him or her

Comment: Check out the tutorial: [ask]  -- you will find lots of useful information to help you edit your post and receive positive feedback

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly